# cross power spectral density explanation in matlab

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density

let us consider following code

```
>> fs=100;
>> t=0:1/fs:2.93;
>> x=25*sin(2*pi*30*t)+20*cos(2*pi*25*t)+10*rand(size(t));
>> y=23*sin(2*pi*30*t)+21*cos(2*pi*25*t)+11*rand(size(t));
```

i would like to ask question related to  Cross Power Spectral Density  function , which in matlab can be easily estimated using function

```
>> cpsd(x,y,[],[],1024,fs)
```

[image]
can this method used tool for identify if two time series have identical spectral structure? i mean suppose we have two time series  which is supposed to have same  spectral structure(periodic components with same frequencies as it is given in our case) can this function help us to proof that give two series have same structure? thanks in advance

Comment: downvoting without explaining reason cool

Answer (score 0):

I think that the picture is more or less what should be expected.  There are strong components at 25 Hz and 30 Hz, which are the frequencies of the tones in $x$ and $y$.  There is also a strong DC (0 Hz) component because the noise has a strong mean, because it ranges from 0 to 1, not -1 to 1.  Without the noise the cpsd looks like this-

[image: CPSD]

Comment: i have updated my picture

Comment: anyway i can say that this function can help me to identify if two time series have same structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "structure"?  But even without knowing that my answer will probably be "no".  It tells you how similarly their power is distributed in the frequency domain.

Comment: by structure i mean spectral  picture for instance let us  suppose that two time series have same frequencies, then we should get peaks only at those frequencies that are containing in both signal right

Comment: it is logical if in one time series there will be  two difference frequencies then we  will get 4  such peaks like we have in our case